# How to await an async delegate correctly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, delegates

While in sync world, I have a TryExecute function to wrap try/catch/log logic for reuse, like this:

```
TryExecute(() => SyncFunction());

private static void TryExecute(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to rewrite it into async/await pattern.

As what I understand, I have five valid ways to rewrite it into async/await (ignore any other Visual Studio has warning).

Using original sync `TryExecute()` with async delegate:

```
(1) TryExecute(async () => await AsyncFunction());
```

It seems not waiting anymore, the `TryExecute()` passes without waiting `AsyncFunction()` to finished.

Rewrite to a new sync `TryExecuteTask()` returns Task, call it with or without async delegate:

```
(2) await TryExecuteTask(() => AsyncFunction());
(3) await TryExecuteTask(async () => await AsyncFunction());

private static Task TryExecuteTask(Func<Task> asyncAction)
{
    try
    {
        return asyncAction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Or rewrite to a new async `TryExecuteAsync()`, call it with or without async delegate:

```
(4) await TryExecuteAsync(() => AsyncFunction());
(5) await TryExecuteAsync(async () => await AsyncFunction());

private async static Task TryExecuteAsync(Func<Task> asyncAction)
{
    try
    {
        await asyncAction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But if I throw `Exception` from inside `AsyncFunction()`, then none of above five ways can catch `Exception`. All stopped with unhandled exception. Only catch without delegate works:

```
(0) try
    {
        await AsyncFunction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
    }
```

That means I can't use any forms of `TryExecute()` from (1) to (5) to reuse the try/catch/log logic, I can only repeating try/catch/log everywhere like (0).

My whole Console code is following:

```
class Program
{
    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Original sync way
        TryExecute(() => SyncFunction());

        Console.WriteLine("0");
        try
        {
            await AsyncFunction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
        }

        ////Console.WriteLine("1");
        ////TryExecute(async () => await AsyncFunction());

        ////Console.WriteLine("2");
        ////await TryExecuteTask(() => AsyncFunction());
        ////Console.WriteLine("3");
        ////await TryExecuteTask(async () => await AsyncFunction());

        ////Console.WriteLine("4");
        ////await TryExecuteAsync(() => AsyncFunction());
        ////Console.WriteLine("5");
        ////await TryExecuteAsync(async () => await AsyncFunction());

        Console.WriteLine("Finished without unhandled exception.");
    }

    private static void SyncFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SyncFunction starting");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("SyncFunction starting");
        throw new Exception();
    }

    private async static Task AsyncFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncFunction starting");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Sleep starting");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep end");
            throw new Exception();
        });
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncFunction end");
    }

    private static void TryExecute(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task TryExecuteTask(Func<Task> asyncAction)
    {
        try
        {
            return asyncAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async static Task TryExecuteAsync(Func<Task> asyncAction)
    {
        try
        {
            await asyncAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void Log(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Because of the unhandled exception, I can only comment out all pieces but one in `Main()` to test every case.

Comment: So that becoms (2)/(3)? But I still don't understand why (1) is not waiting? I have `await` inside the delegate, without any warning and it runs (and passes without waiting).

Comment: What's wrong with `await TryExecuteAsync(() => AsyncFunction())`? What results are you expecting when you call this method? If you want to catch the exception that is re-thrown after the call to `Log` in `TryExecuteAsync`, you should put a `try/catch` clause around the call to `TryExecuteAsync`.

Comment: Functions named [`Try...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) typically don't throw. In case of failure they return false.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers/comments. I made a big mistake to include rethrow in `catch` clause. (some of my `TryExecute` includes `throw`, some not) And returning `bool` is a good guide for `Try...`, but that is even harder for me. Should I edit this question (that makes all current answers/comments off-topic) or ask a new question (and close/delete this question?)? Because I still don't know "How to await an async delegate correctly?".

Answer (score 1):

Calling `await TryExecuteAsync(AsyncFunction)` works like you would expect:

```
class Program
{
    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await TryExecuteAsync(AsyncFunction);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished without unhandled exception.");
    }

    private async static Task AsyncFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncFunction starting");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Sleep starting");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep end");
            throw new Exception();
        });
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncFunction end");
    }

    private async static Task TryExecuteAsync(Func<Task> asyncAction)
    {
        try
        {
            await asyncAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void Log(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`AsyncFunction()` raises an exception that is logged and then rethrown in `TryExecuteAsync`. If you want to catch the rethrown exception, you should put a `try/catch` around the call to `TryExecuteAsync`:

```
async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        await TryExecuteAsync(AsyncFunction);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished without unhandled exception.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to execute: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think `await TryExecuteAsync(AsyncFunction)` is the final answer. If `AsyncFunction` has any parameter, then `await TryExecuteAsync(AsyncFunction(parameter))` won't compile (cannot convert from `Task` to `Func<Task>`). I still need the lambda expression.

Comment: @ChrisTorng: The final answer to what question? What is your point? If `AsyncFunction` takes a parameter, then pass a parameter to it and change `Func<Task>` to something else like `Func<int, Task>`?

Comment: `TryExecute` needs to be reusable to every cases. My form of `TryExecute(() => AsyncFunction())` can accept from no parameter to any number/kind of parameters. I can even wrap many statements inside the lambda expression. For your suggestion, I need a `TryExecuteInt(Func<int, Task> asyncFunc, int intValue)` with `await asyncFunc(intValue)` and call it with `TryExecuteInt(AsyncFunction, 1)`. It's not reusable to other cases and not acceptable to me. My reusable code is `TryExecuteAsync(() => AsyncFunction(1))` or even `TryExecuteAsync(() => { AsyncFunction1(1); AsyncFunction2("a", 1);})`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how to rewrite it into async/await pattern.

When converting to `async`, the first step is to convert what your method *calls*. In this case, the delegate should be converted to an async-compatible delegate first.

`Action` is a delegate that takes no parameters and has no return value, like `void Method()`. An asynchronous method that takes no parameters and has no return value looks like `async Task Method()`, so [its delegate type would be `Func<Task>`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html).

Side note: it's especially important when dealing with delegates to remember that [`async void` is unnatural and should be avoided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Once you change your delegate type from `Action` to `Func<Task>`, you can `await` its return value, which causes your `TryExecute` method to be changed to `async Task`, as such:

```
private static async Task TryExecuteAsync(Func<Task> asyncAction)
{
  try
  {
    await asyncAction();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Log(ex);
    throw;
  }
}
```

> none of above five ways can catch Exception. All stopped with unhandled exception.

That's actually just a side effect of running the code in the debugger. With asynchronous code, you do sometimes see "unhandled" exceptions that are not actually unhandled. This is because it's the compiler-generated code that is catching the exception and placing it on the task, where it will later be re-raised when your code `await`s it and then your code will `catch` it. The debugger gets a bit freaked out when the original exception caught by something *other* than your code (it's caught by the compiler generated code), and it has no way of knowing that this is perfectly normal.

So if you just continue past the debugger's "unhandled" exception, you'll see it works just fine.

Comment: You should have seem my `TryExecuteAsync`, so I already know how to change `Action` into `Func<Task>`. My question is still in "how to await", so hoping you show me whether (4)/(5) is correct or none of them. And I'm sure that unhandled `Exception` is not because of the debugger, but my rethrow in `catch` clause, that's my fault in the question.

Comment: [Either (4) or (5) are correct; they do the same thing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).